# Guardar emoji en base de datos

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, php5

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de un web chat con php y jquery, a este chat le agregue la opción de usar emojis, estoy usando el plugin `EmojiOne Textarea Picker`

Esto es lo que tengo de código:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "textarea" ).emojionePicker({
   pickerTop: 5,
   pickerRight: 1,
   type: "unicode"
  });

  setInterval(function(){ ajax(); }, 1000);
});

function ajax()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:  'chat.php',
        success: function(response){
            $("#chat").html(response);
        }
     });
}
```

HTML:

```
<?php
 include_once("class.Database.php");
?>
<div id="contenedor">
 <div id="caja-chat"> 
  <div id="chat">
  </div>
 </div>
 <form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre">
  <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
 </form>
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST["enviar"]))
  {
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $mensaje = trim($_POST["mensaje"]);

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO chat(nombre, mensaje, fecha) VALUES('$nombre', '$mensaje', NOW())";
    $ejecutar = Database::insert($consulta);

    if($ejecutar)
    {
        echo "<embed loop='false' src='audio/pling_facebook.mp3' hidden='true' autoplay='true'>"; 
    }       
  }
 ?>
</div>
```

chat.php

```
<?php
include_once("class.Database.php");

function formatearFecha($fecha)
{
    return Date("g:i a", strtotime($fecha));
}

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id_chat DESC";
$ejecutar = Database::select($consulta);

if(is_array($ejecutar))
{
 foreach($ejecutar as $fila)
 {  
?>
  <div id="datos-chat">
   <span style="color: #1C62C4;"><?php echo $fila["nombre"]; ?>:</span>
   <span style="color: #848484;"><?php echo $fila["mensaje"]; ?></span>
   <span style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;"><?php echo formatearFecha($fila["fecha"]); ?></span>
  </div>
<?php
 }
}
?>
```

El problema es que el emoji que se selecciona no lo guarda correctamente en la base de datos pues lo guarda así: `????` con esos signos de interrogación.

Como podria hacer para solucionar esto??

Comment: Que motor de base de datos usar? Si usas mysql, prueba con el charset: Utf8mb4 y el cotejamiento: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: @varTob así es, tuve que cambiar el cotejamiento de utf8 a utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: Excelente!, voy a responder en la sección de respuestas para que marques como resuelta tu pregunta, además te recomiendo editar tu pregunta mencionando que usas MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En un motor de base de datos MySQL para `guardar emojis` de manera correcta debes usar como charset **Utf8mb4** y cotejamiento **utf8mb4_unicode_ci**, te respondo basándome en mi experiencia trabajando con Laravel, moodle, wordpress.

Te dejo un ejemplo de como crear/editar una bd y una tabla con los charset/cotejamientos mencionados:

```
CREATE DATABASE `myDatabase` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 */;

USE myDatabase;

CREATE TABLE `miTabla` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emoji` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `field` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Editar base de datos y tabla existente:

```
-- editar base de datos
ALTER DATABASE `myDatabase` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

-- editar tabla
USE myDatabase;
ALTER TABLE `miTabla` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: agrega las referencias a tu respuesta y si es posible un trozo de codigo para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida

Comment: Genial a mi me funciono, muchas gracias. Estoy usando Quill JS como editor y me mostraba los emoji de esta manera. ¿emoji?